# Error with trigger on Oracle apex 5

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex 5 trying to make a trigger that triggers when a record is added. It should prevent the party size being less than 1 and bigger than 6.

here is my code

```
create or replace trigger PARTYSIZE_CHECK
before
insert or update of PARTYSIZE
on BOOKING
for each row
begin
        if (:new.PARTYSIZE<1 or :new.PARTYSIZE>6)
    then raise_application_error(-20601,
           'Party Size of ' || :new.PARTYSIZE || ' is too high, must be between 1 and 6. ';
  end if;
end;
```

When I run the code in SQL commands, I receive the following error:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error.
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the right parenthesis in call to raise_application_error

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it to

 raise_application_error(-20010,'Party size must be between 1 and 6');
 end if;

Comment: What happens now then?

Answer (score 1):

I know, it is almost a 2-years old discussion.

However, trigger is probably not a solution one should choose - CHECK constraint seems to be more appropriate in this case. Something like

```
CREATE TABLE booking
  (partysize   INTEGER CONSTRAINT ch_party CHECK (partysize BETWEEN 1 AND 6));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why CHECK is preferred in this case?

Comment: Quote from Oracle 12c Database Administration book, PL/SQL Language Reference, chapter 9: PL/SQL Triggers, here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS99888: "Oracle strongly recommends that you use triggers to constrain data input only in these situations ..." - for anything else, you should use constraints.